# Mercurial: Merge two local repos

Tags: version-control, mercurial, merge, tortoisehg

I'm using `Mercurial` with `TortoiseHg` on a Windwos host.

We have a central repository for the team and it must always be in a stable state.

Now I'm working on a feature with a colleague and we want to merge our work, without going via the central repository because our work isn't stable yet.

So we have a common ancestor, then we have individual commits to our local repos and we need to merge this work and test it, before pushing it to the central repo.

How do we do that?

As a an additonal difficulty, I'm working on `Windows` with `TortoiseHg`, while my colleague is on a `Linux` box. We're both only basic users of `Hg`, so apologies if this is a question with an evident solution. For me it isn't.

Comment: Was it helpful for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can use named branches and create special named branch (pushed to central repo) for your WIP
2. You can use Mercurial in true DVCS-way:

   - Start embedded web-server on both sides `hg serve` in the Working Directory
   - Get URL of repo
   - Pull from remote side `hg pull URL-OF-REMOTE-REPO`